# Finding the longest word without these characters follow-up

Tags: performance, c, strings, file

[Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/211366/183642) I asked this question:

> My goal is to go through the [list of all English words](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words) (separated by
>   `'\n'` characters) and find the longest word which doesn't have any of
>   these characters:  "gkmqvwxz". And I want to optimize it as much as
>   possible

I updated the code with the help of suggestions from answers, but I still need comments on this updated version

Changes:

1. Name of the file and the forbidden characters are no longer hard-coded. They are passed by arguments.
2. Added several error checks.
3. Used pointers instead of indexes.
4. `buffer` is freed when we're done with it.
5. Used `bool` instead of `int` for the return type of `is_legal`.
6. Parameters to `is_legal` are made `const` since we don't change them.
7. Skip next lines (`'\n'`) remaining from previous lines.
8. Added some functions to keep main simple.
9. Removed superfluous headers (`#include <string.h>`, `#include <stddef.h>`, `#include <unistd.h>`).
10. `is_legal` need not know about the entire `buffer`. Just the relevant pointers are now sent.
11. `length` is no longer fixed. We get the size of the array at runtime
12. `buffer` is terminated with null.

Updated code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


static inline bool is_legal(const char* beg, size_t size, const char* bad)
{
    for (; size-- !=0 ; ++beg) {                                 /* go through current word */
        char ch = tolower(*beg);                                /* The char might be upper case */
        for (const char* bad_ptr = bad; *bad_ptr; ++bad_ptr)
            if (ch == *bad_ptr)                                 /* If it is found, return false */
                return false;
    }

    return true;                                                /* else return true */
}

static inline size_t get_next_word_size(const char* beg)
{
    size_t size = 0; /* resulting size */
    for (; beg[size] && beg[size] != '\n'; ++size) /* read the next word */
    { } /* for loop doesn't have a body */
    return size;
}

static inline char* get_buffer(const char* filename)
{
    char *buffer = NULL;                     /* contents of the text file */

    size_t length;                 /* maximum size */
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (!fp) {                               /* checking if file is properly opened */
        perror("Couldn't open the file\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)) {
        perror("Failed reading");
        return NULL;
    }

    length = ftell(fp);

    if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET)) {
        perror("Failed reading");
        return NULL;
    }

    buffer = malloc(length + 1); /* +1 for null terminator */

    if (buffer == NULL) {                   /* checking if memory is allocated properly */
        perror("Failed to allocate memory\n");
        free(buffer);
        return NULL;
    }

    fread(buffer, 1, length, fp);           /* read it all */
    fclose(fp);

    buffer[length] = '\0';                  /* terminate the string with null*/
    return buffer;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: FileName BadChars");
        return 0;
    }

    char* filename = argv[1];
    char* badchars = argv[2];

    char *buffer = get_buffer(filename);

    if (buffer == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    const char *beg = buffer;               /* current word boundaries */
    size_t size = 0;

    const char *mbeg = beg;                 /* result word */
    size_t msize = 0;

    while (beg[size]) {
        beg += size + 1;                 /* +1 to skip the '\n' */
        size = get_next_word_size(beg);  /* get the size of the next word */

        if (size > msize && is_legal(beg, size, badchars)) { /* if it is a fit, save it */
            mbeg = beg;
            msize = size;
        }
    }

    printf("%.*s\n", msize, mbeg);  /* print the output */

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I would especially appreciate comments regarding the way the code reads the entire file into a single dynamically allocated array. About if and how it could be improved. I wouldn't like to sacrifice the performance, but some "best practices" especially about this part are very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Questionable Design**

The idea to read in the *entire* file and then process it has weaknesses:

1. Code can only handle files fit-able in memory.  Risks allocation failures.
2. Limitations with file sizes more than `SIZE_MAX` and `LONG_MAX`.

Code could read in 1 "word" at a time.

If performance is an issue, then read in perhaps a block of memory at a time.

**Expand uses**

Consider if `argc == 2`, then with a stream view of the file as suggested above, `stdin` could be used as the input.  This makes for a useful "pipe-able" tool.

```
foo | Ayxan_filter "gkmqvwxz"
```

**Certainly a bug on first word**

Code's first call to `get_next_word_size()` is `get_next_word_size(1)`,  I'd expect `get_next_word_size(0)`

Perform a  `size++` at the end of the loop rather than a `+ 1` at the beginning.

**Wrong type**

Precision specifier should be `int`, else code is UB.

```
// printf("%.*s\n", msize, mbeg);
printf("%.*s\n", (int) msize, mbeg);
```

We can assume `msize <= INT_MAX` too, but pedantic code would check that first.

**Questionable processing with binary mode**

File is opened in binary mode `"rb"` yet looks for `'\n'` as end-of-line.  I can foresee trouble with text files that end lines with `"\r\n"` or the rare `"\r"`.

For me, to be highly portable, I would still open in binary mode but use the presence of `'\n'` or `'\r'` as an end-of-line.

**Code can quit early**

Should the file contain a *null character*, its presence will stop the search early.

Robust could would not treat the file as a *string*, but as a character array.

**Resource leak**

`fclose(fp);` missing from various error returns from `get_buffer()`.

**`islower()`**

`islower(int ch)` is defined for values in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`.  Calling it with a `char` can lead to undefined behavior with a negative value.

```
// char ch = tolower(*beg); 
char ch = tolower((unsigned char) *beg);
```

**`is_legal()` alternative**

```
// No need for size, but append '\n' to the `bad` before this call.
static inline bool is_legal(const char* beg, /* size_t size, */ const char* bad) {
   char *y = strcspn(beg, bad);
   if (y == NULL) return true;
   return *y == '\n';
}
```

### Strongly recommend:

To really move things along, rather than search each character to see it it is in a list of bad ones, create a table  (I'd do all using `unsigned char`)  This is reasonable as long as `UCHAR_MAX` is a sane a value.  I suspect this will measurable improve performance.

```
bool bad_boys[UCHAR_MAX+1];
foo_populate(bad_boys, bad);

// Insure '\0', '\n' are true.
static inline bool is_legal_alt2(const char* beg, const bool *bad_boys) {
   const unsigned char* ubeg = (const unsigned char*) beg;
   while (!bad_boys[*ubeg]) {
     ubeg++;
   }
   return *ubeg == '\n' || ubeg == '\0';
}
```

**Code assumes `size_t` is like `long`**

The length returned is a `long`.  Its range may be more or less than `size_t`.  Better code would not assume either.

```
//size_t length;
//length = ftell(fp);
size_t length;
long ilength = ftell(fp);

#if LONG_MAX >= SIZE_MAX
// >= used here rather than > due to later +1 in the allocation
if (ilength >= SIZE_MAX) {
    perror("Too big\n");
    return NULL;         
}   
#endif

// Unclear what risks you want to take here.
// Suggest to just bail out
if (ilength < 0) {
    perror("Unclear size\n");
    return NULL;            
}

length = (size_t) ilength;
```

**No check for `ftell()`, `fread()` error**

An error here is critical and not so improbable.

```
ilength = ftell(fp);
// add
if (ilength == -1) {
    perror("ftell error\n");
    return NULL;            
}

//fread(buffer, 1, length, fp);  
if (fread(buffer, 1, length, fp) != length) {
    perror("fread error\n");
    return NULL;            
}
```

**Questionable style**

Consider a `while` loop

```
//for (; beg[size] && beg[size] != '\n'; ++size) /* read the next word */
//{ } /* for loop doesn't have a body */

while (beg[size] && beg[size] != '\n') {
  ++size;
}
```

**Unneeded `free()`**

No need for call `free(NULL)`;

```
 if (buffer == NULL) {
    perror("Failed to allocate memory\n");
//  free(buffer);  // not needed
    return NULL;
}
```

**Consider sentinels**

A "word" may have leading/trailing spaces.  In a pathological case, the longest word will be `""`.  Consider sentinels characters to show clearly the word.

```
//printf("%.*s\n", msize, mbeg);
printf("\"%.*s\"\n", msize, mbeg);
```